# Как зафиксировать ширину button при удалении текста в нем

Tags: css

Есть код:

```
<button onclick="ProfileEditor.saveContacts(this)">Сохранить</button>
```

При удалении текста "Сохранить" ширина кнопки уменьшается до содержимого в ней. До размеров блока span.
Как сделать, чтобы ширина была фиксированная для текста любой длины в ней?

```
<button onclick="ProfileEditor.saveContacts(this)"><span class="process"></span></button>
```

Comment: Походу без JS никак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задать фиксированную ширину для кнопки, через свойство css - width.

Comment: А если текст в кнопке будет больше фиксированной ширины?

Comment: Тогда поиграться со свойствами min-width, max-width.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/84LJK/ - может так